# How can I select the past seven days and its corresponding week in the past year

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I select

1. The past week
2. Its corresponding days in the year before

This is needed for a dashboard, I would like to show a chart with results from the past seven days. It displays green if our call-center handles 98% of their phone calls within a certain time-span, red if we go over 98%. As a reference I would like to create a chart below with the corresponding seven days in the year before. This is challenging, because weekdays really influence the workload. That means I can't compare a Tuesday with a Sunday or Monday.

For instance, today is Saturday 21st Dec 2019, I would like to report the following timespans:

**2019-12-13 00:00:00 -> 2019-12-20 23:59:59**
and
**2018-12-14 00:00:00 -> 2018-12-21 23:59:59**

I made the following code (used within a select statement):

```
case when cs.ReachedAt between (getdate() - 7) and getdate() then 1 else 0 end as Is_PastWeek

case when cs.ReachedAt between (convert(datetime, convert(varchar(50), convert(date, dateadd(d, -1, dateadd(wk, -52, getdate())))) + ' 23:59:59')) and (convert(datetime, convert(varchar(50), convert(date, dateadd(d, -8, dateadd(wk, -52, getdate())))) + ' 00:00:00')) then 1 else 0 end as Is_SameWeekLastYear
```

It works, but isn't perfect. I just select the corresponding weekday in the same week as 52 weeks ago. Which means I sometimes end up selecting a matching weekday, but not the nearest. How can I do this better?

**EDIT**

To clarify what I mean by "picking the nearest corresponding weekday in the year before", i made the following example:

```
with cte1 as (
select row_number() over (order by (select 1)) - 1 as incrementor
  from master.sys.columns sc1
 cross join master.sys.columns sc2
), cte2 as (
select dateadd(day, cte1.incrementor, '2000-01-01') as generated_date
  from cte1
 where dateadd(day, cte1.incrementor, '2000-01-01') < getdate()
), cte3 as (
select convert(date, generated_date) as generated_date     
     , convert(date, getdate()) as now_date
  from cte2
), cte4 as (
select * 
     , convert(date, dateadd(YEAR, -1, now_date)) as year_back
  from cte3
)
select now_date
     , generated_date
  from cte4 
 where 1=1
   and datepart(week, year_back) = datepart(week, generated_date)
   and datepart(DW, year_back) = datepart(DW, generated_date)
```

This will result in:

[image: results]

For the grey values, I would rather take the weekday of one week later. That way I pick "the nearest corresponding weekday in the year before".

Please note that the above is an example to show what I mean, my ultimate goal is to start with this date, select the whole week before... And all (if possible) neatly within a where clause.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `datepart(week, getdate())` will deliver you the calendar week. With this, you can go further.

Comment: I think I see what you mean: dateadd(WEEK, datepart(week, getdate()), convert(date, convert(varchar(4), (year(getdate()) - 1)) + '0101')). That is an improvement, but would you also know a way to select the corresponding weekday?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

What difference does it make?  If you are looking for the past week, just look at the same 7 days from the previous year.  In one case the week might start on a Tuesday and in the other on a Wednesday.  But in both cases, each weekday occurs once.

The logic would be:

```
where cs.ReachedAt >= datefromparts(year(getdate() - 7) - 1, month(getdate() - 7), day(getdate() - 7) and
      cs.ReachedAt < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), day(getdate()))
```

The logic for the current year:

```
where cs.ReachedAt >= convert(date, getdate() - 7) and
      cs.ReachedAt < convert(date, getdate())
```

Comment: Because this is a chart that changes by the day, I want to select the nearest corresponding weekday. So if today is Saturday 21 Dec 2019, I would like to select the Saturday nearest to 21 Dec 2018. Although I talk in weeks, this is actually something that changes by the day, on Monday my week goes from Monday to Sunday, but on Tuesday it goes from Tuesday to Monday.

Comment: @Steef . . . And my point is that that does not matter.  A week has all seven weekdays, regardless of when it starts.  So just take seven days that include the date one year before.

Comment: Gordon: He wants to compare weekdays of corresponding *calendar weeks*.

Comment: @SQLPolice . . . You might interpret the question that way, but I definitely do not read it that way.  The "past seven days" is only going to correspond to a "calendar week" once every seven days.

Comment: @GordonLinoff For example, take the 7 days from Wed, Dec 11 2019 to Tue Dec 17, 2019. This range lies in calendar weeks 50 and 51. Therefore, in 2018, you need to look for Calendar week 50, and then compare. The range is then Wed Dec 12, **2018** to Tue Dec 18, **2018**.

Comment: @SQLPolice . . . That seems reasonable.  But it does not seem to be what the question is asking for.